# Phonegap app error handling, submit log to server

Tags: cordova

I am developing a Phonegap app, so I am thinking is there a good way to submit app crash report (mainly console.logs of javascript) to the server somehow or do I have to do it manually and log it to a text file and submit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an error tracking service that tracks JavaScript errors to get information on your errors. [Bugsnag](https://bugsnag.com) is a good choice. The [Bugsnag JS notifier](https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-js) should work well with Cordova/Phonegap.

Answer (score 2):

Another service that captures JavaScript errors is [Atatus](https://www.atatus.com/).  It also works with Cordova/PhoneGap.

> https://www.atatus.com/
>
> You can check out the docs at https://www.atatus.com/docs

Answer (score 0):

use `adb logcat | grep CONSOLE` to see every console() output from JS