# Preventing duplicate entry in database before inserting value into database

Tags: mysql, cordova, mobile, duplicates, sql-insert

I am trying to check the database to see if the activity Name that I am entering already exists, if it exists I should get an error if it don't it should go ahead and insert values into database, below is the code I am trying but it isn't working properly btw the prevention of duplicates is already working cause of the UNIQUE KEY i give to activity Name but I also want an alert to let the users know that the activity name already exists.

```
function insertQueryDB(tx) {
        var myDB = window.openDatabase("test", "1.0", "Test DB", 1000000);
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dataEntryTb (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, activityName TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, location TEXT NOT NULL, time NOT NULL, date NOT NULL, reporter NOT NULL)');
            var an = document.forms["myForm"]["activityName"].value;
            var l = document.forms["myForm"]["location"].value;
            var t = document.forms["myForm"]["time"].value;
            var d = document.forms["myForm"]["date"].value;
            var r = document.forms["myForm"]["reporter"].value;
            if('COUNT activityName FROM dataEntryTb WHERE EXISTS activityName = "'+an+'" '){
            navigator.notification.alert("activityName already Exists");
            }
            var query = 'INSERT INTO dataEntryTb ( activityName, location, time, date, reporter) VALUES ( "'+an+'", "'+l+'", "'+t+'", "'+d+'", "'+r+'")';
            tx.executeSql(query,[]);

            navigator.notification.alert("Retrieved the following: Activity Name="+an+" and Location="+l);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is establish an unique key on activityName...

```
alter table dataEntryTb add unique key (activityName);
```

Comment: where do I have to put line?

Comment: it is changing your table definition...  you can enter in your interface (i.e., MySQL command line client, MySQL workbench, toad, etc...)   The rule will be enforced going forward - activityName will not be duplicated.

Comment: If you have dups... you will need to remove them...  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861594/removing-duplicate-sql-records-to-permit-a-unique-key

Comment: but isnt activity name already unique when I create the table, its already preventing duplicates from happening its just I want give an error to the user so they would know why they were unable to enter the value

Comment: You are correct - the unique constraint and the unique key are the same thing.  You should be getting an error when a duplicate value is attempted - the question is how to handle the error.     I don't know if this is any help...   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775493/phonegap-app-error-handling-submit-log-to-server